# Using svg-url-loader with Create React App

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using Create React App, and I'd like to include my SVG inline as a data URI.

I know CRA allows me to import and render an SVG as a component, a la:

```js
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
// <Logo />
```

And I know I can get the URL of the SVG:

```js
import Logo from './logo.svg';
// <img src={Logo} />
```

But what I'd like to do is embed the contents of the SVG as a data URI, as in:

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg>...</svg>">
```

I know [svg-url-loader](https://github.com/bhovhannes/svg-url-loader) can do this. So I set it up (using [Rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts), because CRA restricts modifying the Webpack config):

```js
function addSvgLoader(config) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.svg/,
    use: {
      loader: "svg-url-loader",
      options: {
        limit: 15000,
      },
    },
  });

  return config;
}

module.exports = [addSvgLoader];
```

With this, in theory, I should be able to use my second example above and instead of getting a fingerprinted URL, get an inline data URI. However, the fingerprinted URL is still rendered, and the contents of the SVG file now look like this:

```
module.exports = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg role='img' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 24V0h24v24H0zM ... [truncated] ... 03h-.52l-.23.02z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"
```

I suspect this is a conflict between CRA's loader `svg-url-loader`, but I haven't been able to find a solution. If there is an alternative to `svg-url-loader` I would consider that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack Rules use the `test` glob for a Rule to process inclusive files when using the `import` syntax. Since rules don't have to be mutually exclusive, multiple rules can easily process on the same `test` criteria.

In your example, it sounds like the pre-existing CRA rule for svgs **and** your `svg-url-loader` rule are processing the imported SVG; the order being dictated by how your Webpack config allocates at runtime.

Try something like:

1. Create a variation of your SVG with an identifiable moniker in the filename (ex. `my-image.data-uri.svg`)
2. Configure the `svg-url-loader` plugin to activate for the `*.data-uri.svg` glob pattern

   ```
   {
     test: /\.data-uri.svg/,
     use: {
       loader: 'svg-url-loader',
       options: {
           encoding: 'base64'
       },
     },
   },
   ```

The filename here is really like an `intent` and the rule will route those cases through the custom plugin at build time.

## Note

If attempting this outside of modern CRA, older static compilation strategies recommended specifying the import intent in the require statement:

```
require('svg-url-loader?encoding=base64!./file.svg');
```

This has generally been dropped in favor of static mapping, hence the need to use the glob test to activate your special plugin case.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed a conflict between CRA's svg loader and the one you're trying to use. However, webpack rules can have a [`oneOf`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleoneof) section, which will apply only the first matching rule - and [CRA's svg rule is in it](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/fa648daca1dedd97aec4fa3bae8752c4dcf37e6f/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L380) (my version is `3.4.1`).

Also, the order of the rules matter, and your rule should come before the rules defined by CRA.

Keeping both in mind, I modified the webpack config like so:

```
let oneOfRule = config.module.rules.find((r) => r.oneOf);
oneOfRule.oneOf.splice(0, 0, {
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: ['svg-url-loader'],
});
```

I tested this with svg-sprite-loader and not svg-url-loader, but the general principle remains the same and it should work.